# The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

Estoy realizando un programa en C# que ataca a una base de datos Oracle 12C que se encuentra en otra maquina virtual, si me conecto usando el SQL Developer no tengo problemas, me conecto y puedo trabajar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora intento entrar desde codigo y me sale el error indicado en el titulo de la pregunta **The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.**

La cadena de conexion es la siguiente:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.87)(PORT = 1521)) 
 (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = PRUEBA)));
   User Id=SYSTEM;Password=PASS;
```

He probado usando la version v4.0.30319 de Oracle.DataAccess y tambien la version v2.0.50727.

He compilado para x86 y para Any CPU.

La base de datos esta en un WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2 Standar de 64 bits.

He comprobado que hay ping en ambos sentidos de las maquinas.

Estoy un poco desesperado porque no se que mas probar, si alguien me puede ayudar quedaria muy agradecido.

P.D: El nombre del servicio no es PRUEBA pero por seguridad haremos como si lo fuera

Edit 1:

```
 _cnn_string = this.tCadena.Text.ToString();
        this._cnn = new OracleConnection(_cnn_string);
        try
        {

            this._cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Conexión correcta!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!: " + ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        { this._cnn.Close(); }
```

La cadena de conexion esta puesta en un textbox a pelo para hacer las pruebas y es la siguiente:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.87)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = PRUEBA)));User Id=SYSTEM;Password=PASS;
```

Añadida imagen del InnerException
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es oracle o sql server??? ahi me mareaste.. y podrias poner el codigo con el cual te conectas?? el data source tambien me suena raro..

Comment: Primera vez que oigo que se puede instalar una bbdd oracle en un SQL Server. No te referiras a Windows Server? :)

Comment: @Pikoh Tienes razon, llevo tanto tiempo con los SQL Server 2012 que he escrito mal el nombre del Servidor, gracias.

Comment: Puedes mirar en la innerexception de la excepcion que pone y lo pegas aqui?

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que dice @Pikoh y tambien aclarar que clase estas usando? probaste con otras cadenas de conexion mas simples?

Comment: Bueno,pues ahi tienes el problema. "El proovedor no es compatible con la versión del cliente Oracle"

Comment: Añadida la innerException, La clase que uso es: OracleConnection, que es la que proporciona la referencia Oracla.DataAccess. Gracias

Comment: @Pikoh Si, es cierto, pero no se que version o que clase tengo que usar, he usado la  v4.0.30319 de Oracle.DataAccess y tambien la version v2.0.50727

Comment: prueba con oledb o genera un udp para conectarte por fuera de todo, a ver si se genera una conexion.. ya se que son mas lentas, pero es lo primero que hay que probar...

Comment: Yo no suelo usar Oracle, pero veo al parecer que necesitas tener las dll en la misma carpeta que el ejecutable y que las versiones deben coincidir. Echa un vistazo a [este enlace](http://oradim.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/odpnet-provider-is-not-compatible-with.html) por ejemplo

Comment: Muchas gracias, ire probando

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido solucionarlo cambiando el proveedor de Oracle, en vez de usar **Oracle.DataAccess.Client** he utilizado **Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver 12.2.1100** de la pagina https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Gracias a todos por la ayuda